# Azure Data Factory SHIR - issue with on-premise Oracle Linked Service

Tags: azure-data-factory

we ran into a very strange issue and Microsoft is trying to help but it takes ages and few smarter brains than mine couldn't point it out either.. so "you're my only hope!"
We use Data Factory V2 to copy data from an Oracle server on premise (which is to say inside our Network) to Azure SQL Database. Being a connection transiting intra/inter net the way to go according to Microsoft is via the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime. So we set up 4 WinSvr2016 VMs on premise, installed SHIR client version 5.10.7918.2 on each, register, create a Linked Service using Oracle connection, created the datasets for source and sink, pipelines, etc.. It was working for months, data in, good speed, all good.
Until it wasn't! Last Thursday we turned these pipelines on again to run another extract, as per hundreds times before and BOOM, nothing, the error:

```
Error code 9603, Details: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed. ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Connection Dead.
```

That's it! On SHIR Logs I can see a similar error, bit more detailed but still not very helpful:

```
TraceComponentId: QueryTask
TraceMessageId: QueryRuntimeTestConnectionV2Exception
@logId: Error
FunctionName: TestConnection
jobId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
activityId: 390a17f1-d1f3-4ceb-b38a-11e4e51e3009
eventId: QueryRuntimeTestConnectionV2Exception
message: TestConnection failed, error message: 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed.
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Connection Dead.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,StackTrace=   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector.OdbcSourceUtilities.OpenOdbcConnection(IOdbcConnection connection, Int32 maxRetryAttempts, Boolean needWrapOdbcException, TimeSpan connectionTimeout) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.OdbcConnectorValidator.TestConnection()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.InteractiveTaskFactoryV2.ConnectorTestConnection(ConnectionSetting connectionSetting, TestConnectionV2Response response)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.InteractiveTaskFactoryV2.TestConnection(TestConnectionV2Request request, TestConnectionV2Response response, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.InteractiveTask`2.Execute(),''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Interop.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed.
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Connection Dead.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Wrapper,StackTrace=   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Api.OdbcConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HelperMethod.ExecuteWithTimeout(Action action, TimeSpan timeout, HybridDeliveryExceptionCode exceptionCode, String errorMessageFormat)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector.OdbcSourceUtilities.OpenConnectionInternal(IOdbcConnection connection, TimeSpan connectionTimeout)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.RetryPolicies.RetryExtension.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.RetryPolicies.RetryExtension.ExecuteAction[TResult](IRetry retry, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector.OdbcSourceUtilities.OpenOdbcConnection(IOdbcConnection connection, Int32 maxRetryAttempts, Boolean needWrapOdbcException, TimeSpan connectionTimeout),'.
```

Now, we started with the connectivity, tested the VNet and firewalls, private endpoints and all that jazz trying to figure out WHAT could have happened last Thursday as nobody recalls anything in particular.
All seems OK, the SHIR nodes are visible from Azure, and I can connect to Oracle using same credentials from the SHIR (the clients have that small diagnostic utility). More, I setup an **ODBC** Linked Service to connect to the same Oracle server and it's working fine, it's working - only it's so slow and not that smart (no schemas, no partitions, etc) it'll take ages to re-write the pipelines to use the ODBC and it's 20 times slower than a native Oracle linked service, tested!!
We then changed the SHIR VMs to WinSvr2019, changed the SHIR client to an older one, moved the SHIR VMs in Azure and tried from there, move them back and changed credentials, service accounts and what not. All in vain, same error anything we try to our desperation:

```
Error code 9603, Details: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed. ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Connection Dead."
```

Is anyone here seen this before? Or has any idea what else is in the chain and we possibly didn't try?
Thanks for any suggestion!
Cheers, DanG

Comment: Which version of Oracle database do you use?

Comment: Hi Nadine, it's 19c Enterprise

Comment: If I understood correctly, the SHIR is online. Did you test the Oracle linked service? If it fails, what do you have as a response? Does the error only happen when you execute a pipeline?

Comment: Sorry, Nadine, appreciate the intention, your questions are all answered in my text above - which I admit is a bit too long but hey, it's a complex story. Cheers

Comment: Update: Microsoft did the preliminary investigations and the network is good, triple hand shakes good, the request arrives at the Oracle server which in turn replies "Fatal NI connect error 12637 TNS-12637: Packet receive failed" Thus Microsoft at this stage suspects an issue with the Data Factory Oracle Driver, warning for all lucky ones out there using Data Factory's "Microsoft Oracle ODBC Driver 8.0.2.2473", Cheers, DanG

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you manage to resolve this in the end? Thanks!